# How I can make express server serve only one API request at a time

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have exposed one API from node express server and I want only one request to be served (due to resource constraints) and other request should just simply be denied. Anyway to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

use LOCK

```
let lock = false

router.get('/myroute', (req, res, next) => {
    if (lock) {
        req.json({err: 'server busy'})
        return
    }
    lock = true
    // process main functions
    ....
    res.json(result)
    lock = false
})
```

variable 'lock' is shared to every requests. if one request is requested and set lock to true, other requests which arrived later counter lock is true.

Answer (score 1):

Use **express-rate-limit**, especially if you want to implement if repeatedly for multiple routes.

`npm install --save express-rate-limit`

```js
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

const limiter = rateLimit({  
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 1 // limit each IP to 1 request per windowMs
});

//  apply to all requests
app.use(limiter);

// only apply to requests that begin with /api/
app.use("/api/", limiter);

// only apply to single route
app.post("/create-account", limiter , function(req, res) {
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one NodeJS thread that executes your API handler in Express. Simply do not use any async code in the API handler and this goal

> I want only one request to be served (due to resource constraints)

will be achieved automatically.

> and other request should just simply be denied

Is it really necessary? The stated goal related to resource constraints can probably be met if other requests are made to wait.